# How to refactor JQuery interaction with interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The question is very simple but also a bit theoretical.

Let's imagine you have a long jQuery script which modifies and animate the graphics of the web site. It's objective is to handle the UI. The UI has to be responsive so the real need for this jQuery is to mix some state of visualization (sportlist visible / not visible) with some need due to Responsive UI.

Thinking from an MVC / AngularJS point of view. How should a programmer handle that?
How to refactor JS / jQuery code to implement separation of concerns described by MVC / AngularJS?

I provide an example of jQuery code to speak over something concrete.

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    /*variables*/
    var sliderMenuVisible = false;

    /*dom object variables*/
    var $document = $(document);
    var $window = $(window);
    var $pageHost = $(".page-host");
    var $sportsList = $("#sports-list");
    var $mainBody = $("#mainBody");
    var $toTopButtonContainer = $('#to-top-button-container');

    /*eventHandlers*/

    var displayError = function (form, error) {
        $("#error").html(error).removeClass("hidden");
    };
    var calculatePageLayout = function () {
        $pageHost.height($(window).height());
        if ($window.width() > 697) {
            $sportsList.removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody
               .removeAttr("style")
               .unbind('touchmove')
               .removeClass('stop-scroll');
            if ($(".betslip-access-button")[0]) {
                $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            } 
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
        } else {
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeOut(500);
        }
    };
    var formSubmitHandler = function (e) {
        var $form = $(this);

        // We check if jQuery.validator exists on the form
        if (!$form.valid || $form.valid()) {
            $.post($form.attr("action"), $form.serializeArray())
                .done(function (json) {
                    json = json || {};

                    // In case of success, we redirect to the provided URL or the same page.
                    if (json.success) {
                        window.location = json.redirect || location.href;
                    } else if (json.error) {
                        displayError($form, json.error);
                    }
                })
                .error(function () {
                    displayError($form, "Login service not available, please try again later.");
                });
        }

        // Prevent the normal behavior since we opened the dialog
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    //preliminary functions//
    $window.on("load", calculatePageLayout);
    $window.on("resize", calculatePageLayout);

    //$(document).on("click","a",function (event) {
    //    event.preventDefault();
    //    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
    //});

    /*evet listeners*/

    $("#login-form").submit(formSubmitHandler);

    $("section.navigation").on("shown hidden", ".collapse", function (e) {
        var $icon = $(this).parent().children("button").children("i").first();
        if (!$icon.hasClass("icon-spin")) {
            if (e.type === "shown") {
                $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-right").addClass("icon-caret-down");
            } else {
                $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-down").addClass("icon-caret-right");
            }
        }
        toggleBackToTopButton();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(".collapse[data-src]").on("show", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data("loaded")) {
            var $icon = $this.parent().children("button").children("i").first();
            $icon.removeClass("icon-caret-right icon-caret-down").addClass("icon-refresh icon-spin");
            console.log("added class - " + $icon.parent().html());
            $this.load($this.data("src"), function () {
                $this.data("loaded", true);
                $icon.removeClass("icon-refresh icon-spin icon-caret-right").addClass("icon-caret-down");
                console.log("removed class - " + $icon.parent().html());
            });
        }
        toggleBackToTopButton();
    });

    $("#sports-list-button").on("click", function (e)
    {
        if (!sliderMenuVisible)
        {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "0" }, 500);
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "85%" }, 500)
                .bind('touchmove', function (e2) { e2.preventDefault(); })
                .addClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeOut(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "-85%" }, 500).removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "0" }, 500).removeAttr("style")
                .unbind('touchmove').removeClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $mainBody.on("click", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            $sportsList.animate({ left: "-85%" }, 500).removeAttr("style");
            $mainBody.animate({ left: "0" }, 500)
                .removeAttr("style")
                .unbind('touchmove')
                .removeClass('stop-scroll');
            $(".betslip-access-button").fadeIn(500);
            sliderMenuVisible = false;
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    $document.on("click", "div.event-info", function () {
        if (!sliderMenuVisible) {
            var url = $(this).data("url");
            if (url) {
                window.location = url;
            }
        }
    });

    function whatDecimalSeparator() {
        var n = 1.1;
        n = n.toLocaleString().substring(1, 2);
        return n;
    }

    function getValue(textBox) {
        var value = textBox.val();
        var separator = whatDecimalSeparator();
        var old = separator == "," ? "." : ",";
        var converted = parseFloat(value.replace(old, separator));
        return converted;
    }

    $(document).on("click", "a.selection", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var isLive = $this.data("live");
        var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/Add/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;
        var urlHoveringBtn = "/" + _language + '/BetSlip/AddHoveringButton/' + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

        $.ajax(urlHoveringBtn).done(function (dataBtn) {
            if ($(".betslip-access-button").length == 0 && dataBtn.length > 0) {
                $("body").append(dataBtn);
            }
        });

        $.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
            if ($(".betslip-access").length == 0 && data.length > 0) {
                $(".navbar").append(data);
                $pageHost.addClass("betslipLinkInHeader");
                var placeBetText = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("placebettext");
                var continueText = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("continuetext");
                var useQuickBetLive = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("usequickbetlive").toLowerCase() == "true";
                var useQuickBetPrematch = $("#live-betslip-popup").data("usequickbetprematch").toLowerCase() == "true";
                if ((isLive && useQuickBetLive) || (!isLive && useQuickBetPrematch)) {
                    var dialog = $("#live-betslip-popup").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        dialogClass: "fixed-dialog"
                    });
                    dialog.dialog("option", "buttons", [
                        {
                            text: placeBetText,
                            click: function () {
                                var placeBetUrl = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/QuickBet?amount=" + getValue($("#live-betslip-popup-amount")) + "&live=" + $this.data("live");
                                window.location = placeBetUrl;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: continueText,
                            click: function () {
                                dialog.dialog("close");
                            }
                        }
                    ]);
                }
            }
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $this.addClass("in-betslip");
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "a.selection.in-betslip", function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        var $this = $(this);
        var isLive = $this.data("live");
        var url = "/" + _language + "/BetSlip/RemoveAjax/" + $this.data("selection") + "?odds=" + $this.data("odds") + "&live=" + isLive;

        $.ajax(url).done(function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                $this.removeClass("in-betslip");

                if (data.selections == 0) {
                    $(".betslip-access").remove();
                    $(".betslip-access-button").remove();
                    $(".page-host").removeClass("betslipLinkInHeader");

                }
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("section.betslip .total-stake button.live-betslip-popup-plusminus").click(function (e) {
        if (sliderMenuVisible) {
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        var amount = parseFloat($(this).data("amount"));
        if (!isNumeric(amount)) amount = 1;

        var totalStake = $("#live-betslip-popup-amount").val();
        if (isNumeric(totalStake)) {
            totalStake = parseFloat(totalStake);
        } else {
            totalStake = 0;
        }
        if (action == "decrease") {
            if (totalStake < 1.21) {
                totalStake = 1.21;
            }
            totalStake -= amount;
        } else if (action == "increase") {
            totalStake += amount;
        }
        $("#live-betslip-popup-amount").val(totalStake);
    });

    toggleBackToTopButton();

    function toggleBackToTopButton() {
        isScrollable() ? $toTopButtonContainer.show() : $toTopButtonContainer.hide();
    }

    $("#to-top-button").on("click", function () { $("#mainBody").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }); });

    function isScrollable() {
        return $("section.navigation").height() > $(window).height() + 93;
    }


    var isNumeric = function (string) {
        return !isNaN(string) && isFinite(string) && string != "";
    };

    function enableQuickBet() {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking a high level question, so I am going to give a high level answer.

- Your listeners should have at most 2 lines of code inside, 1 line that changes data in the model if required, one line that updates the screen, if required.

This means that you need to extract from your listeners all the code into functions which you can group under a view object, this will help tremendously for reviewing since you can give meaningful names to those functions so that the reader knows what is going on.

- Your data should live in a model class, you can keep updating the model from the UI or you can let Angular take care of that.

Other than, I do have some other minor observations:

- Remove commented code out, it has no use, use source versioning
- Magic constants, you have so many, extract them out, name, explain their value

Comment: Thanks! But what are magic costants?

Comment: 697, 500, "85%", 1.21, 93 are magic constants, "Unique values with unexplained meaning or multiple occurrences which could (preferably) be replaced with named constants"